# how can I use Juniper.register in julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

the code was written in Julia 1+.

```
using JuMP,Gurobi, Ipopt
#parameters--------------------------------------------------------
sig=0.86;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALT= Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Juniper.Optimizer, "nl_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0), "mip_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Gurobi.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0)))

# variables-----------------------------------------------------------------
f(x) = cdf(Normal(0, 1), x);
JuMP.register(ALT, :f, 1, f; autodiff = true);
@variable(ALT, h >= 0);
@variable(ALT, L >= 0);
@variable(ALT, n, Int);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLexpression(ALT,k7,1-f(L-sig*sqrt(n))+f(-L-sig*sqrt(n)));
#constraints--------------------------------------------------------
@NLconstraint(ALT, f(-L) <= 1/400);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLobjective(ALT, Min, 1/k7)
optimize!(ALT)
```

but this error was happened

ERROR: Have you registered a function? Then please register the function also for Juniper see:
https://lanl-ansi.github.io/Juniper.jl/stable/options/#registered_functions%3A%3AUnion%7BNothing%2CVector%7BRegisteredFunction%7D%7D-%5Bnothing%5D-1

then the code was changed as follow

```
using JuMP,Gurobi, Ipopt
#parameters--------------------------------------------------------
sig=0.86;
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ALT= Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Juniper.Optimizer, "nl_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0), "mip_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Gurobi.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0)))

# variables-----------------------------------------------------------------
f(x) = cdf(Normal(0, 1), x);
JuMP.register(ALT, :f, 1, f; autodiff = true);
Juniper.register(ALT, :f, 1, f; autodiff = true);
@variable(ALT, h >= 0);
@variable(ALT, L >= 0);
@variable(ALT, n, Int);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLexpression(ALT,k7,1-f(L-sig*sqrt(n))+f(-L-sig*sqrt(n)));
#constraints--------------------------------------------------------
@NLconstraint(ALT, f(-L) <= 1/400);
#-------------------------------------------------------------------
@NLobjective(ALT, Min, 1/k7)
optimize!(ALT)
```

but again this error was happened
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching register(::Model, ::Symbol, ::Int64, ::typeof(f); autodiff=true)
would you please help me about those error? thank you

Comment: it is worked ```ALT= Model(optimizer_with_attributes(Juniper.Optimizer, "nl_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Ipopt.Optimizer, "print_level" => 0),

       "mip_solver"=>optimizer_with_attributes(Gurobi.Optimizer, "logLevel" => 0),"registered_functions" =>[Juniper.register( :f, 1, f; autodiff = true)])

       )```. Thanks very much :)

Comment: For people in the future, this is explained in the [link given in the error message](https://lanl-ansi.github.io/Juniper.jl/stable/options/#registered_functions::Union{Nothing,Vector{RegisteredFunction}}-[nothing]).

Comment: Seems like it works now! Please feel free to ask questions like this directly in the issues section or ping me @Wikunia in the Julia Lang slack (I'm the main developer of Juniper  )

Comment: @Wikunia. if you don't mind,  would you please help me about the question in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63590997/what-is-nonlinearconstraintindex-in-julia/63592879#63592879.